# How to bring to next line in textview for string array?

Tags: java, android, string, replace

I have string array items but for every completion of one element, i need to move to next line.

```
String[] word = { "This is text1.So it should be single line", "This is text2", "This is text3" };

broadcastMessage.setText("" + Arrays.toString(word).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
```

But this output makes to display as,

```
This is text1.So it should be single line ,this is text2,this is text3.
```

Expected output: (there should be no comma and should be next line).

```
This is text1.So it should be single line
This is text2
This is text3.
```

But output should be in every single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    

    String[] word = {"This is text1.So it should be single line", "This is text2", "This is text3"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textureView1);
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            textView.append(word[i]);
            textView.append("\n");
        }



    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks. To remove the comma?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
broadcastMessage.setText("\n" + Arrays.toString(word).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:singleLine = "false"` in xml and 
`broadcastMessage.setText("\n" + Arrays.toString(word).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
String abc="" + Arrays.toString(word).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
    abc.replaceAll(",","\n");
    broadcastMessage.setText(abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] words = {"This is text1.So it should be single line", "This is text2", "This is text3"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        for (String string : words) {
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "\n" + string);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8+ you can use the following code with lambda expression:

```
String[] word = { "This is text1.So it should be single line", "This is text2", "This is text3" };
String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
Arrays.asList(word).forEach(w -> broadcastMessage.append(w+separator));
```